# How to convert hourly rainfall data into daily rainfall

Tags: matlab

I have hourly rainfall and other data for long period. I would like to get daily values from these hourly data. My daily values should start from hour 1 to hour 24.

```
Year  Month  Day  Hour  Rain  RH Temp

1976   1     1    1     3.4   60 16 

1976   1     1    2     0     80 18

1976   1     1    3     NaN   50 18
```

Comment: Where are your problems? In reading the file, in the calculations? Please post whatever code you already have and describe where you are facing problems.

Comment: Hi Filburt, I really don't know where to start, I'm new in Matlab/programming.I have 35 years of hourly data, I need to calculate the mean of each day rainfall, RH and Temp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of NaN's, because e.g. `1+NaN=NaN`, so it destroys any summation, average etc.

Then you can do for example simply this:

```
% M_hourly is a matrix with rows [Year Month Day Hour Rain RH Temp]
[H,W]=size(M_hourly);    
for ii=1:24:H
   Rain=M_hourly(ii:ii+23,5);
   Rain_daily(ii)=sum(Rain);
end
```

You should prealocate the `Rain_daily`, cause it grows inside a loop.
I could be more helful, if you provide us with a more specific questions. I am just guessing what is the problem.

Comment: OK, if you want a mean, not a sum, use a `mean` not a `sum`. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I need to generate a new matrix where it will show: Year, Month, Day, mean rainfall (average of hour 1 to hour 24). Does that shed more light to my previous question?

Comment: OK, implement the suggested code as a function and let the `Rain_daily` to be the output. Check whether the data are reasonable and then adjust the Year, Month, Day.